# Teradata: How can I raise an error in a stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, teradata

Is there a way to raise errors inside of Teradata stored procedures?

For example, I want to check if a table is empty.  If the table is empty I wish to cause the stored procedure to error out with the error message "Table Empty".

That will allow me to bubble up the error to the calling application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TD13+ implements [Standard SQL's SIGNAL/RESIGNAL](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_111A/ch07.141.103.html).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That should work.

We are running Teradata 13.10.07.04