# simple way to output messages from a stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Using SQL*Assistant:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE l_msg varchar(128);
  set l_msg = 'test';

  -- PRINT is not supported
  --print l_msg;

  -- debug is recognized as a special token, but doesn't work
  --debug l_msg;

  -- this does nothing
  --SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000';

END;
```

Is there a simple way to output a text during a procedure execution, aside writing to a log table?

TD 14.xx

EDIT:
Not trying to handle exceptions, but rather send text messages to the client, as the procedure progresses, regardless of the state/condition, similar to PRINT (Sybase), DMBS_OUTPUT(Oracle), DEBUG(SQL Server).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399461/teradata-how-can-i-raise-an-error-in-a-stored-procedures - SIGNAL should work.

Comment: @Rob, you're talking about exception handling, whilst I was looking for a continuous spool of text messages regardless of error states, similar to DBMS_OUTPUT (Oracle) or PRINT (Sybase). I mean yes, we can use output params or log tables, but what about debug messages, esp. for procedures that are long running?

Comment: You are going to probably need a combination of conditional handlers and possibly signal statements to accomplish what you want. I would refer to the SQL Stored Procedures and Embedded SQL manual for details. I wouldn't rule out using a log table either.

Comment: I also have this question. I have a stored procedure with several insert statements within. I want to print the latest insert so I can see what is happening.