# Teradata Raise Error

Tags: teradata, raise, custom-error-handling

I'm making a stored proc in teradata v16 that requires me to raise an error. I can see how to make the code to capture an error (see below) but cannot figure out how to raiseerror as you can with other applications. Can some show me how to raise an error?

```
    BEGIN
  DECLARE SQL_ERR_CDE INTEGER;
  DECLARE SQL_STATE INTEGER;
  DECLARE TMPMSG VARCHAR(133);

L1: BEGIN
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SqlException
        BEGIN
          SET SQLERRCDE = SqlCode;
          SET SQLSTTE = SqlState;
          SET SQLMSG = TMPMSG;
          SET SQL_ERR_CDE = SqlCode;
          SET SQL_STATE = SqlState;
          INSERT INTO DW.ERR_STD_PRC_LOG
          VALUES ('DW', 'SP_INDEX_STATS' , 'E' , :SQL_ERR_CDE,:SQL_STATE, :TMPMSG, DATE, TIME);  
        END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ABORT?  This should error out the SP call with whatever message you want to include:

```
ABORT 'Error Message';
```

https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/hch1472240804504.html

Also, take a look at this for how to use SIGNAL: [Teradata: How can I raise an error in a stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399461/teradata-how-can-i-raise-an-error-in-a-stored-procedures)

Comment: I started to post an answer about SIGNAL then noticed that it is included in your second link :-)

Comment: Updated my post :)

Comment: I know about signal. But its not going to help because what I need to do is get the error handler to send out an email to stakeholders of the report the SP makes after I raise some custom errors